# LAMPSecurity CTF8

Tags: security, penetration-testing

I am trying to use this code that was provided to me for a penetration test exercise. According to the author that created this you enter this code and it will get the users hashes from a machine we are trying to compromise. When I enter the code it does not return anything from the database. All I get is a ":" on the screen. Something does not seem right with this code can you please help. My job is not to fix the code but to just query the information from the database to get the hashes for the users. I am just going based up on the instructions of the LAMPSecurity CTF8 pdf that was provided to me.

```
 <?php

  $res = db_query('select name,pass from users');

  while ($rec = db_fetch_object($res)) {

  print $rec→name . ":" . $rec→pass . "<br/>";

  }

  ?>
```

Comment: Does the character `→` look right to you?

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean

Comment: This is the code i am using

Comment: well how do i insert the arrow?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere during the parsing of your PDF, the characters `->` have been turned into the UTF8 equivalent of `→`.

However, `→` is not a valid operator in PHP.

Replace `→` with `->` and try again.

Also, your code doesn't connect to the DB anywhere, so that may cause further issues.